Installing solana spl from terminal ubuntu 24.1
what is the command for installing solana spl on ubuntu 24.1? looking for a sudo apt install line because the curl command is not found. I already have rust installed

Try installing the curl command using apt
sudo apt install curl

Also make sure you have these essential packages installed as well
sudo apt install \
    build-essential \
    pkg-config \
    libudev-dev llvm libclang-dev \
    protobuf-compiler

You can also download the pre-build libraries from the releases page.
solana-install-init-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu for Linux in your case
